# Parsing timestamps with Python regular expressions ':' character not found

Tags: python, regex

I am teaching myself python and I am trying to implement the regular expression to obtain a timestamp from an application log file ( I normally use *grep*, *cut* and *awk* for this )

My logfiles contain many lines started with date and time next

```
18.12.19 14:03:16 [ ..... # message error
18.12.19 14:03:16 [
:
```

I normally use a simple grep command `grep "14\:03\:16" mytext`
and this expression works "14:03:16", so after researching I came up with this regex:

Where `res` is one of the lines above

```
datap = re.compile(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')
m = datap.match(res)
```

This does not find anything whereas

```
datap = re.compile(r'(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2})')
m = datap.match(re
```

Captures the date.

Why the character `:` is not found? I have tried to use `\:` as well and it also does not work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you grouping inside of the colons for a reason? `r'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}'` will match  the full time string inculding colons.

Comment: You mean using parenthesis to group them?

Comment: Sorry, I got, I need to group them because I will use the specific  hour , minute second to trace elapsed times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) tries to match the regex from the beginning of the string.

From the docs:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
>   Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
>   is different from a zero-length match.

When you did

```
datap = re.compile(r'(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{2})')
m = datap.match(res)
```

the regex actually matched the date, not the time (because it is at the beginning of the string):

```
print(m)
# <re.Match object; span=(0, 8), match='18.12.19'>
```

If you use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) then you will get the expected output:

```
import re

res = '18.12.19 14:03:16 [ ..... # message error'
datap = re.compile(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})')
m = datap.search(res)
print(m)
# <re.Match object; span=(9, 17), match='14:03:16'>
```

Comment: if your time stamp at the beginning of your string then use carrot '^' . It worked for me on regex 101   /^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/

Comment: @JBone `re.match(regex_string, string)` is *usually* equivalent to `re.search('^' + regex_string, string)`

Comment: thank you. I don't know Python yet, so thanks for that information.